# How can I render a D3.js visualization as a JPG, or an image?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I built an interface using ASP.NET 4.5, C# and D3.js where I mapped out the organs and bones for a human body. The problem is that when I try to print, it almost never prints out properly, and my users want to have a "Save Image" button next to the visualization so they can import the saved image into their own Word/PowerPoint end of months reports.

I'm not sure if I need to post my code. I'm just loading some SVG I have traced in Illustrator, saved it in a JSON file and loaded into D3.

I know print screen could be an option, but saving as an image could also help me display multiple files without overloading my browser with D3 code.

Comment: search for `canvas.toDataURL()`

Comment: Oh wow i didnt know that existed! Thanks Gusman I will read up on this and try it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically d3.js works with SVG. You could directly download `.svg` image from your d3.js work tho.

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/vicapow/758fce6aa4c5195d24be) is an example (from Mike Bostock, d3.js creator) where he goes from SVG to PNG step by step.

He uses several tricks including XML Serializing, Blob objects (kinda file-like object for raw data ([about](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob))) and finally create another PNG image from the SVG using `canvas.toDataURL()`. Please look at the source, it quite interesting and useful to understand differences.

Hope it helps

`pltrdy`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Like Gusman mentioned above as well, the canvas.toDataURL() was something I didn't know and I was searching using the wrong way i.e i was trying to search how to screenshot certain regions of a webpage and save that to clipboard etc. But im glad there is a better way now.